# Assigning numeric values to column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, read.csv, data-preprocessing

I'm a beginner so sorry in advance if I'm unclear :)

I have a .csv with 2 columns, doc_number and text. However, sometimes the rows start with the doc number (as they should) and sometimes it just starts with text from the previous row. All input is the type 'object'. There are also many empty rows between the inputs.

How can I make sure doc_number consists of all the numeric values (doc_numbers are random numbers of 8 digits) and text is the text, and remove the empty rows?

**Example of what it looks like:**

```
69353029, Hello. How are you doing?


What are you going to do tomorrow?


59302058, Tomorrow I have to go to work.


58330394, It's going to rain tomorrow


45801923, Yesterday it was sunny.


Next week it will also be sunny.


68403942, Thank you.
```

**What it should look like:**

````
_doc, _text
69353029, Hello. How are you doing? What are you going to do tomorrow?
59302058, Tomorrow I have to go to work.
58330394, It's going to rain tomorrow.
45801923, Yesterday it was sunny. Next week it will also be sunny.
68403942, Thank you.```
````

Answer (score 0):

also just learnning *to panda*, so maybe not the best solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#reading .csv and naming the Headers, - you can choose your own namings here
df = pd.read_csv("text.csv", header=None, names = ["_doc","_text"])

# updating _text column emty cells with values from _doc
df["_text"] = np.where(df['_text'].isnull(),df["_doc"],df["_text"])

# change dtype to int (it will generate <NA> in strings) and back to str to aggregate later
df["_doc"] = df["_doc"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").astype("Int64").astype(str)

# aggregating rows if below value is <NA> and joining strings in col _text
df = df.groupby((df["_doc"].ne("<NA>")).cumsum()).agg({"_doc":"first","_text":" ".join}).reset_index(drop=True)

# converting back to int (if needed)
df["_doc"] = df["_doc"].astype(int)
print(df)
```

out:

```
       _doc                                              _text
0  69353029   Hello. How are you doing? What are you going ...
1  59302058                     Tomorrow I have to go to work.
2  58330394                        It's going to rain tomorrow
3  45801923   Yesterday it was sunny. Next week it will als...
4  68403942                                         Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I can think of when looking at the dataset. It looks like a `CSV` file which translates to an unnamed column (representing `_doc`) with mixed `integers` and `strings` and another unnamed column with strings (representing `_text`)

Since, it has to be csv, I created the following [dummy.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EJvVCMeTBcR2EMT5x1hqiUhBO3h8-GoR/view?usp=sharing) file.
I would turn the `CSV` into a dataframe and add the initial column titles `mixed` and `text` as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv', header= None)
df.columns = ['mixed', 'text']
df
```

which results in the data frame `df` for cleaning:

[image: initial dataframe]

What we can do is separate the `mixed` column into two different columns `m_numeric` and `m_text`. This can be done by creating the `m_numeric` column using
`to_numeric(,errors='coerce')` and non-numeric strings masked to `m_text` column as follows:

```
df['m_numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mixed'], errors='coerce')
mask = df['m_numeric'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'm_text'] = df.loc[mask, 'mixed']
```

[image: separated df]

We can now fill the `NaN` values in `m-numeric` using `ffill` from [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) which propagates last valid observation forward to next valid backfill. Similarly, we can fill the original `text` columns `NaN` with the strings from `m_text` as follows:

```
df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].astype(int)
df['text'] = df['text'].fillna(df['m_text'])
```

[image: ffill]

Now we have the final columns we need as `text` and `m_numeric` on which we can apply the pandas groupby() function. We groupby the `m_numeric` column and use `.apply` to join the strings in two rows separated by a space. Finally we can rename the column names to `_doc` and `_text` as follows:

```
df = df.groupby('m_numeric', sort= False)['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
df  = df.rename(columns= {'m_numeric' : '_doc',
                   'text' : '_text'})
```

**Result:**

[image: final df]

**Complete Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv', header= None)
df.columns = ['mixed', 'text']

#separate column
df['m_numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mixed'], errors='coerce')
mask = df['m_numeric'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'm_text'] = df.loc[mask, 'mixed']

#replace nan values  
df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].astype(int)
df['text'] = df['text'].fillna(df['m_text'])

#group by column
df = df.groupby('m_numeric', sort= False)['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
df  = df.rename(columns= {'m_numeric' : '_doc',
                   'text' : '_text'})

df
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I've tried this and it seems to be working, until I try to fill the NaN values. I get this error: IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer.

Comment: You can usually apply `df = df.fillna(0)` to replace the NaNs with ) and then convert them to integers using `astype(int)`. Additionally, you can cross-check if your CSV file is in a similar form as my dummy.csv file. If the error still exists, you can share a sample of the dataset so I can inspect it.

Comment: Hello, i've tried to apply the whole code, but i keep running into errors. Unfortunately I can't copy paste any of the code, because it's in an offline separate environment, but I can explain what I did. I changed 
df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].fillna(method='ffill') to df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].fillna(0) because I wanted to convert NaN to zero

Comment: Then I got the error expected str instance, float found. So I tried int(0, inplace=True), but that also gave an error: int() must be a string

Comment: Okay, right before you start with the section for `#replace nan values` check the Dtype for the dataframe using `df.info()`. Depending on the data type of the corresponding column, you convert it's type before applying fillna. So in this case, as I can't see your dataframe, the best I can suggest is try the following steps in order (line by line) after checking `df.info()` : First `df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].astype('Int64')` second: `df['m_numeric'] = df['m_numeric'].fillna(0)`

Comment: you can also additionally include 'ignore' while using `.astype('int', errors='ignore')` if the error still exists